# expand height of jumbotron to cover whole column height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using bootstrap 4.0.0, I have the following code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="jumbotron mt-3 container-fluid" style="padding: 0.6em 1.6em;">
    <h5>Title</h5>
    <p style="font-size: 14px;">text text text</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"> Click me </button>
  </div>
</div>

... repeated many times

</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to create a grid of 3 by *x* jumbotrons. I am not able to expand the height of the jumbotrons as to cover 100% of the given row in which they are. Each one is with their own height. The ideal is that the `<h5>` and the `<p>` are top-aligned, while the `<button>` is bottom-aligned.

How can I achieve the above? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the flexbox utils for the jumbrotrons.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="jumbotron mt-3 h-100 d-flex flex-column align-items-start" style="padding: 0.6em 1.6em;">
          <h5>Title</h5>
          <p style="font-size: 14px;">text texttext</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mt-auto"> Click me </button>
     </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/4uafEjOFdn

- `h-100` - make jumbotron fill height of col
- `d-flex flex-column` - `display:flex` the jumbotron the content vertically
- `align-items-start` - align content down the left side
- `mt-auto` - align bottom on the bottom

Related: [Bootstrap 4 cards - align content at the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49385263/bootstrap-4-cards-align-content-at-the-bottom)

Comment: Thanks. What if I wanted the bottom to be bottom-center? mt-auto becomes?

Comment: Use auto-margins for alignment `mt-auto mx-auto`